# jQuery Address - Deep linking and states

Tags: jquery, ajax, deep-linking

I am rather new to AJAX, and is currently learning how to implement jQuery Address on a demo site so that I could port it over to a personal project that I'm working on.

While I am able to load the desired content through hyperlinks as well as modify the URL hash, I am unable to navigate to a particular state if I enter the URL hash directly in the browser bar.

The current code goes something like this:

```
$("h2.entry-title a").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").fadeOut("slow").load($(this).attr("href")+" #content > *", function() {
        $.address.value("?page=entry");
    }).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

I tried looking for tutorials and demos about using jQuery Address to implement deep linking, but so far it yielded nothing fruitful.

Thanks for all your help :)

p/s: The reason why I used `.live()` instead of `.bind()` is because at some point more entry titles will be inserted dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in this code that reads the url when you first load a page. If you type in the address bar 'http://test.com/test.html?page=entry' then you need to load in the content at page load, when the hash is manually changed, and on click events.

http://abishaigray.com/jquery.address.php

```
$(function() {
    var content = $("#content");
    var loadUrl = function(url) {
        content.fadeOut("slow", function() {
            content.load(url + " #content > *", function() {
                    content.fadeIn("slow");
                });
        });
    };
    $("a.loadUrl").live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.address.parameter("page", $(this).attr("href"));
    });
    $.address.change(function(vars) {
        var page = $.address.parameter("page");
        if (page) { loadUrl(page); }
    });
});
```

I took advantage of the `$.address.change` event. In this way, anytime you update the url or when a user first arrives the content will be reloaded.

Comment: I have an inkling that I have to use $.address.change at some point, but I have no idea how to implement it. Do you have a simple example to illustrate that? Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Sure, see below.

`$.address.change(function (vars) { alert('the url changed!'); });`

Also, read through the [jQuery Adress Docs](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/)

Comment: Thanks. I read through the docs and also the examples a few days ago, but still struggling to understand how it works. I have an example here that illustrates how `$.address.change()` works - http://jsfiddle.net/5L6Ur/9/ 

However, what bothers me is how can I navigate the user to the correct state when they enter a state-specific URL? I'd expect some regex, but haven't found anything in the examples thus far.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the example, and I have a few questions... I hope you really don't mind me bothering you.

When I viewed the source code, it seems that the hyperlinks in the example go by "jquery.address/p1.html". Why does it start with "jquery.address"?

One more question. What does `$.address.parameter("page", $(this).attr("href"));` actually do?

Comment: No problem. The hyperlinks contain "address.jquery" because that's the folder they're in. It has nothing to do with jQuery. It's just a URL.

The `$.address.parameter` method allows you to get or set querystring variables. So, I'm setting a querystring variable ("page") to the links href.

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it working, and now I'm trying to understand the code and it's going great. One final, final question - not sure if it warrants me asking a new one or as a comment, but, is it possible to have multiple ajax calls in one page, for example, two links when clicked, leads to dynamic content being loaded in different parts of the page?

Comment: That will not cause a problem. I would caution you, though. A properly designed app will avoid making more calls than necessary.

Comment: You have a point. I have revised the design and layout a little, so that I would not make unnecessary, additional calls :) thanks for the help all the while, anyway!